# TestNg all Tests are skipping

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse

when I execute the my Testng code always the tests are Skipped. I got the below error
**FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest beforeTest**

Below my code Snippet

```java
@Test(dataProvider = "bhaskar") 
public void f(String xpath,String values,String action,String browser) { 
    if(browser.contentEquals("common")) { 
        switch(action) { 
            case "openurl" : openurl(values); break; 
            case "verifytitle": verifytitle(values); break; 
            case "click": click(xpath); break; 
            default: System.out.println("keyword not found");
        } 
    }
} 

//-------------------------------------

public void openurl(String values) { 
    driver.get(values); 
}

public void verifytitle(String values) { 
    String title=driver.getTitle(); 
    Assert.assertEquals(title, values); 
} 

public void click(String xpath){ 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click(); 
    System.out.println("clicked"); 
} 

@DataProvider(name="bhaskar") 
public String[] dp() { 
    String[] a=new String[] {"","w3schools.com/","openurl","common" }; 
    return a; 
}
```

Comment: **Below is my code**

Comment: Edit the question and put your formatted code, that will be easy for others

Comment: please find my code in the above question(i edited)

Comment: The problem comes from "@BeforeTest beforeTest". You should share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestNG, for some reason, does not always print stack traces for unhandled exceptions from configuration methods (e.g. `@BeforeTest`). Try wrapping your code from your configuration methods in a try-catch and print the stack trace yourself or try debugging and/or add logging to your configuration methods.

Comment: now the test is running, but all the tests are failed. i got the below exception **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:**

Comment: @PalaBhaskar That's good, you are now one step closer to finding the root cause. I recommend POSTing a new question including details on your configuration method if you do not know why you are getting the exception.